# How to force spring-security to redirect unauthorized users to a specific page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jakarta-ee, struts2, spring-security

My application perfectly submits a form to server and shows the response message received from server such as "form is submitted" or "sorry, something went wrong!"

However, I need to allow all users visit the form page but only authorized user should be able to submit the form. So I use Spring security, which is configured to redirect users to index page if they are attempting to access a secured page.

Up to here every thing works fine, but the problem is that, since I am using message.jsp page to show the server returned message, once an unauthorized user tries to submit the form, the index page will be shown as body of message.jsp page, and since message.jsp page is used to show the messages it will show the index.jsp page in my form.jsp page.

How to solve the issue ? Or how to show the server messages on the form.jsp page to avoid this issue?

**form.jsp**

```
  function Add(value){
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            } 
        }
        xmlhttp.open("get","add?myvalue="+value,false);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    .....

     form goes here

    <label id="msg"></label>
```

**formSubmit.java**

```
private String ServerMessage;
  public String add(){
    ....
    if(result)
      this.ServerMessage = "form is submitted";
    else
      this.ServerMessage = "sorry, something went wrong!" 
    return "successful";   
}
....
```

**struts.xml**

```
<result name="successful">message.jsp</result>
```

**message.jsp**

```
   required library goes here
   <s:property value="ServerMessage"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

add something like:

`<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/403.jsp</location>
</error-page>`

to your `web.xml`. Http Error 403 will be thrown if user is not authorized to access given url, it will based on **user_role** defined in spring-security.
for e.g.

```
<intercept-url pattern="" access="" />
```

where pattern denotes your url pattern. and access contains the role to which pattern is accessible. Pattern could be like `/index/**` or `/index` itself. have a look on [official documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html) of spring security.

( make sure you have proper jsp formed at particular location.  in my case **403.jsp** is located under `WebContent` directory.)

Comment: I used your code but still the same problem, question is updated

Comment: can you share your url mapping mentioned in spring-security here ?

Comment: <http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/error.jsp" use-expressions="true"> <form-login login-page="/index" 
                authentication-failure-url="/index?error=1"
                default-target-url="/default"/> 
    <remember-me/>
     <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp"/>

Comment: Jack, u havn't mentioned <intercept-url pattern="" access="" /> tag in your security file.. that may be an issue. I would like to share  http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html  please have a look on it.

Comment: I have that I just did not mention it to make it shorter

Comment: Please note, my application redirects unathorized users successfully but the problem is that, I am using message.jsp page to show the messages so when application is going to redirect users it puts the redirect page in the message.jsp page and that will be displayed in my form.jsp page.

Comment: If there is any error, you are redirecting to message.jsp, understood. Now where form.jsp comes into picture? Do you want to display error message in form.jsp itself? then user struts validation framework? if not, you can keep meta refresh=5 etc, so that message.jsp would be displayed for 5 second and then you can redirect user to form.jsp